# javascript - array.sort sorts multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to make some simple 3D graphics. One of the things I need to do with this is figure out the z-order of the faces. I am doing this by calculating the distance of the plane to the camera. I have put these numbers in an array. I then copy it to make a second array. I want to be able to sort this array and compare it to the first one to find the render order of the planes. However, when I try and sort the second array, it sorts the first one as well!

```
for(var i = 0; i < faceDist.length; i++)
{
    sortedDist[i] = faceDist[i];

}
sortedDist.sort(sorter);
for(var i = 0; i < sortedDist.length; i++)
{
    drawOrder[i] = faceDist.indexOf(sortedDist[i]);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like references are being tied together.  Maybe your copy portion need to create new objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new array as a clone of the first, currently it looks like you are saving a reference to it.

try this:

```
var clone = myArray.slice(0);
```